# how to stop kibana (not as a service)?

Tags: linux, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to stop kibana on SSH with `kill` but it respawns immediatly

```
dagatsoin@dagatsoin.io [~/logstash]# ps aux | grep kibana
533      28778  0.0  0.0   9292   876 pts/2    S+   00:16   0:00 grep kibana
dagatsoin@dagatsoin.io [~/logstash]# kill -kill 28778
-bash: kill: (28778) - Aucun processus de ce type
dagatsoin@dagatsoin.io [~/logstash]# ps aux | grep kibana
533      28780  0.0  0.0   9292   876 pts/2    S+   00:16   0:00 grep kibana
dagatsoin@dagatsoin.io [~/logstash]#
```

How do you kill this process ?

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned the output that you are seeing is from the `ps aux | grep kibana` command that you ran. I'm guessing you started kibana using by running the kibana scipt in the bin directory. In this case do something like this:

```
ps -ef | grep '.*node/bin/node.*src/cli'
```

Look for the line that looks something like this:

```
username   5989  2989  1 11:33 pts/1    00:00:05 ./../node/bin/node ./../src/cli
```

Then run a `kill -9 5989` If you have multiple output rows make sure you kill the correct process.

Answer (score 2):

You try to kill your grep process, not kibana service who is not running currently.

Answer (score 2):

For me, nothing worked on Ubuntu 18, except this:

```
systemctl stop snap.kibana.kibana
```

Answer (score 0):

You kibana process is not running. when you do run a `ps aux` command and pipe it with a grep command, grep will be running as a separate process. hence its shows up in the `ps aux` output as process no 28778 or 28780. you can observe that the process number is changing. every-time you stop the `ps aux` grep process also ends as it is piped with `ps` and it starts as a new process(id) when you rerun it. hence you are getting an error when you run `kill -kill 28778` as it has already stopped.

Answer (score 0):

When you start your Kibana using the start script in `$KIBANA_HOME/bin/kibana`, this script runs another script in `$KIBANA_HOME/node/bin/node`. Remember, you must search using `ps` command for a different name (not Kibana name).

So I use `ps awwwx | grep -i ./bin/../node/bin/node | grep -v grep` on new Linux versions like Ubuntu 18 (or `ps -ef | grep -i ./bin/../node/bin/node | grep -v grep` on older versions) to search for the Kibana node. This command will give you the accurate `PID` and you can kill the Kibana node via mentioned `PID`.

`grep -v grep` part of this command is just to omit the unnecessary lines from the output of the command.